# Z_STREAM_ERROR from deflate() on Solaris only

Tags: c, solaris, zlib

We have been successfully using zlib in R's data.table for several months now out in the wild with no problems on Windows (64bit and 32bit), Linux and OSX. But just on Solaris we see an apparent `z_stream` clobber. I don't have access the Solaris machine to debug on it directly but I have a way to submit jobs and see output.

I've confirmed that `zlibVersion() == ZLIB_VERSION == 1.2.11` by outputting these to the log.

I have read and searched the zlib manual and I've searched Stack Overflow.

I have looked for any potential clobbering of the `z_stream` but I can't see where that could be. How can I further debug more detail about the Z_STREAM_ERROR? Are there any known Solaris-only issues?

https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4099

https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/src/fwrite.c

Comment: There are no known Solaris-only issues.

Comment: Hmm.  Is it solaris on sparc? If so maybe an endian-ness config issue? Just a wild guess... I think 64-bit sparc allows choosing endianness of data access in the instruction set.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! Much appreciated. It is 32bit Solaris 10 on i386.  I can certainly add some tests and output to show endianess in the next submission.  I could also dump the contents of `z_stream` to the log file at various points as a trace to see where it might be getting clobbered.  If I had access to the machine I'd put a gdb hardware watchpoint on z_stream, but I'm stuck with tracing via a log file.  I looked at the zlib source of `deflate()` and if I could just gdb it at that point I could see which line was causing the Z_STREAM_ERROR.